# Replacing a TextView with the updated TextView Android

Tags: android, view

I am dynamically adding a TextView in an activity layout. the activity gets values from another activity using startActivityForResult  and then creates a textView dynamically and add particular value to it. 
but the problem is that there is an update button to the same activity when I again get the value and come back to the activity responsible for displaying the textView doesn't update that textView and adds another textView below the previous textView int the layout and it keeps on adding without updating.
I know we can set its visibility to gone but does it removes the textView from the child elements of the layout as well or there is another way to destroy that text view and create another in that place?

**My onActivityResult method:**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentData);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            locationLat = intentData.getDoubleExtra("LocationLat", 0.0);
            locationLng = intentData.getDoubleExtra("LocationLang", 0.0);
            location = locationLat + " "+locationLng;
            if(location != ""){
                Toast.makeText(this, location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                lblName = new TextView(this);
                lblName.setText(location);
                lblName.setId(9);
                lblName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llOne);
                ll.addView(lblName, 5);
                Button btnSetLoc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getLoc);
                btnSetLoc.setText("Change Location");
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "location is not set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check if **lblName** is null or not if it is null then create it else update it

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentData) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentData);
            if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                locationLat = intentData.getDoubleExtra("LocationLat", 0.0);
                locationLng = intentData.getDoubleExtra("LocationLang", 0.0);
                location = locationLat + " "+locationLng;
                if(location != ""){
                    Toast.makeText(this, location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(lblName==null) {
                        lblName = new TextView(this);
                        lblName.setId(9);
                        lblName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llOne);
                        ll.addView(lblName, 5);
                        Button btnSetLoc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getLoc);
                        btnSetLoc.setText("Change Location");
                    }
                    lblName.setText(location);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "location is not set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: sorry @Nilesh it think so it should be lblName == null instead of != and there should be else part for update :|

Comment: btnSetLoc should be outside the if as well

Comment: It depends on your condition modified as you want

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to remove the textview and not change its value?

Changing TextView's text is much cheaper than removing the TextView from Layout and reattaching a new one

If you however want to remove the TextView and attach a new one you can do that by first removing the old one using Layout's removeView method and inserting a new one by using Layout's addView method

You can get the index of the view by calling Layout's indexOfChild method

If you however can achieve what you're trying by just changing the text in the TextView, you can simply use TextView's method setText()

so basicically what this boils down in

```
TextView oldText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oldText);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llOne);
int index = ll.indexOfChild(oldText);
ll.removeViewAt(index);
TextView newText = new TextView(context);
ll.addView(newText, index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your textview in runOnUiThread.

**runOnUiThread** : Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread.

**reference** : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Implementation in your code :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentData);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            locationLat = intentData.getDoubleExtra("LocationLat", 0.0);
            locationLng = intentData.getDoubleExtra("LocationLang", 0.0);
            location = locationLat + " "+locationLng;
            if(location != ""){
                 runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() { 
                public  void  run() { 
                   Toast.makeText(this, location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                lblName = new TextView(this);
                lblName.setText(location);
                lblName.setId(9);
                lblName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llOne);
                ll.addView(lblName, 5);
                Button btnSetLoc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getLoc);
                btnSetLoc.setText("Change Location");
                } 
            }); 

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "location is not set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

For more implementations of runOnUiThread : http://android.okhelp.cz/java_android_code.php?s=runOnUiThread